# Connecting Flex application to Tomcat + Spring 3.0 Framework with BlazeDS

Tags: apache-flex, spring, tomcat, flash-builder, blazeds

I'm developing a web application (client in Flash Builder 4, server in Eclipse 3.6 + Tomcat 7 + Spring 3 Framework). How do I make the Flex client automatically deploy in the Tomcat server and use BlazeDS messaging and remoting more seamlessly?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my free Refcard on [Flex 4 and Spring 3 Integration](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/flex-4-and-spring-3).